# Java mistakes with numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to fix the following Java code,

I cannot figure out why the printout is still 5.

```
public class simpleMath
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int number=5;
        half(number);

        System.out.println("5 divided by 2 is: " + number);

    }

    private static double half(int number) {
         number =  number/2;
         return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: You call your division method, but you don't assign the result from it. Try System.out.println(" 5 divided by 2 is:"+ half(number)); but of course - better is to use variable to hold the result from the operation.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

First you need to be aware of what types you are assigning to your variables. You should change your code to look like this:

```
    public class simpleMath
    {


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            double number = 5;
            double answer = half(number);

            System.out.println(" 5 divided by 2 is:"+ answer);

        }

        private static double half(double number) {
             number =  number/2.0;
             return number;
        }

    }
```

See how I now use the returned value and how I divide by 2.0? these changes will give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: why all the downvotes? I gave a good answer that I know works

Comment: All the downvotes because you do not *solve* the OP's problem, you simply hide it. He is not assigning the return value of `half(number)`, and your solution is to call it again when he prints? This is not going to *help* the OP in any way.

Comment: wow totally missed that. I just ran it and assumed it was right. thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 17):

Because you're not re-assigning the returned value.

```
int number = 5;
number = half(number);
```

Answer (score 9):

When you call the function, you're discarding its return value:

```
half(number);
```

You probably meant to write:

```
number = half(number);
```

Also, in Java, arguments are passed by value. This means that, even though you change `number` inside the function, the change does not propagate back to the caller.

There are several further problems:

**Problem 1:** The suggested change will store the result in `number`, which is an integer variable. Thus, the result of `half()` -- which is of type `double` -- will be truncated to an integer. To avoid the loss of precision, you either have to change `number` to be a floating-point variable, or store the result in a different variable of the appropriate type.

**Problem 2:** The following uses *integer division*:

```
number =  number/2;
```

The result is truncated to an integer, i.e. `5 / 2` is `2`. The latter is then converted to a `double` (2.0), which is what the function returns.

To fix, change the function like so:

```
private static double half(int number) {
     return number / 2.0;
}
```

P.S. Floating-point numbers have a lot of properties that can be unintuitive. I recommend having a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: true, but not really answering the question though is it.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You passing the primitive data type which is done by value. You need to give SOP in method half()
EDIT: Need to use the result returned by method half() by either assigning it to number or calling this method in SOP itself.

Comment: He returns it but he is not assigning it again to `number` variable

Answer (score 1):

Why `half(number)` doesn't modify `number` **declared** in `main()` function? It is because you will pass the value of `number` to `half()` function to evaluate, i.e. you give a copy of value in `number` to `half()` function. Therefore, whatever `half()` function does to `number` will not get reflected back to `number` variable **declared** in `main()`. You need to assign the return value of `half()` to `number` in `main()` if you want to update its value.

There are other cases, such as variable shadowing, that I'm not going to talk in details, since it may confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not assigning the return value of `half()` to `number` - it gets calculated but not used.

You need to say:

```
number = half(number);
```

The way you have it currently would only work if `number` was being passed by reference, not by value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number =5;
half(number);
```

Java doesn't support pass by reference. So In this case we are passing value that is 5 not reference of number.

So if we want to capture the changes then method call should be like this -

```
public class simpleMath
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int number =5;
        number  = half(number);

        System.out.println(" 5 divided by 2 is:"+ number);

    }

    private static double half(int number) {
         number =  number/2;
         return number;
    }
}
```